# Python: In a DataFrame, how do I loop through all strings of one column and check to see if they appear in another column and count them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe and want to loop through all cells within column `c2` and count how many times each entire string appears in another column `c1`, if it exists. Then print the results.

Example df:

```
id     c1                c2
0      luke skywalker    han solo
1      leia organa       r2d2
2      darth vader       finn
3      han solo          the emporer
4      han solo          c3po
5      finn              leia organa
6      r2d2              darth vader
```

Example printed result:

```
han solo      2
r2d2          1
finn          1
the emporer   0
c3po          0
leia organa   1
darth vader   1
```

I'm using Jupyter notebook with python and pandas. Thanks!

Comment: I have NaN values in `c2` which changes some of the solutions below as indicated by @wen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some Numpy magic.
Use `count` and broadcasting to compare each combination.

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import count

c1 = df.c1.values.astype(str)
c2 = df.c2.values.astype(str)

pd.Series(
    count(c1, c2[:, None]).sum(1),
    c2
)

han solo       2
r2d2           1
finn           1
the emporer    0
c3po           0
leia organa    1
darth vader    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know what the "def" stands for? Searching for `numpy.core.defchararray` throws up all the methods, `numpy.core.chararray` throws up all those methods, and searching for the difference is obscured by the fact that [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.chararray.html) is a thing :(

Comment: @roganjosh hah!  No, you've got me there.  I have no idea.

Comment: I have NaN values in `c2`. Is there a way to remove them AFTER the pd.Series is created with this method? I can't remove the rows before because those rows in `c1` could contain the strings for which I'm trying to match.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass them as `category` and using `value_counts`

```
df.c1.astype('category',categories=df.c2.tolist()).value_counts(sort=False)
Out[572]: 
han solo       2
r2d2           1
finn           1
the emporer    0
c3po           0
leia organa    1
darth vader    1
Name: c1, dtype: int64
```

Or you can do

```
pd.crosstab(df.c2,df.c1).sum().reindex(df.c2,fill_value=0)
Out[592]: 
c2
han solo       2
r2d2           1
finn           1
the emporer    0
c3po           0
leia organa    1
darth vader    1
```

Comment: When i try the 'category' option I get an error: `ValueError: Categorial categories cannot be null`

Comment: @mapk it works fine on my side do you have nan in c2?

Comment: Also on the second option, the `fill_value=0` seems to just fill them all with `0`.

Comment: @mapk if you have nan then it is totally different story

Comment: I understand. Can you help me through it?

Comment: @You can fillna with something like df.fillna('NaN')

Answer (score 0):

```
df[c3] = pd.Series([df[c1].count(n) for n in df[c2]])
```

Comment: This is a syntax error since you don't complete your list comprehension. It's also not a good use of pandas at all since you create a whole new DataFrame rather than work with the one that exists. Two good answers were posted 20 mins prior to this; it would be worth reading those and understanding how they used the libraries before posting an answer.